using mongo $toObjectId function in java driver aggregation
I am using a Mongo java driver (version 3.12.12) aggregation to join two MongoDB collections.
The left side collection has a string version of the right side collection's _id field.  Here are some sample docs:
leftCollection:
{ "foreignKey" : "5a43b24cb4eac10001dbafba"}
rightCollection:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a43b24cb4eac10001dbafba", "rightsideField": "some right side stuff")}
I need to transform the leftCollection.foreignKey strings into ObjectIds so that I can use that objectId as the foreign key in a later $lookup stage.  I'm trying to use the $toObjectId mongo aggregation function for that purpose.
Here's the code that does that:
    Bson addForeignKeyObjectId = Aggregates.addFields(new Field("foreignKeyObjId", "$toObjectId:\"$foreignKey\""));

    List<BsonDocument> foo = ImmutableList.copyOf(leftCollection.aggregate(
          ImmutableList.of(
            addForeignKeyObjectId,
          )
      ))

what I'm expecting:
{"foreignKey":"5a43b24cb4eac10001dbafba", "foreignKeyObjId":ObjectId("5a43b24cb4eac10001dbafba")}
what I get:
{"foreignKey":"5a43b24cb4eac10001dbafba"}
Note the desired foreignKeyObjId field is not added.  :(
However, if I replace the $toObjectId expression with a literal like this:
Bson addForeignKeyObjectId = Aggregates.addFields(new Field("foreignKeyObjId", "some bogus literal"));

the new fields are added correctly and the output documents look like this:
{"foreignKey":"5a43b24cb4eac10001dbafba", "foreignKeyObjId":"some bogus literal"}
So, the addFields aggregation step appears to be working correctly, but I suspect I haven't got the syntax of the $toObjectId expression quite right.  Can anyone hint me to the right move here?
(I really really wish we weren't using _ids as foreign keys, everything becomes harder with that approach, but do not have the scope to change this ugliness rn)

You are adding a string instead of an object.  The string  "$toObjectId:\"$foreignKey\"" means to take the value of the field toObjectId:"$foreignKey".  Since that value is missing/undefined, the "created" field is also missing/undefined.
Instead of a string, create an object with a field named $toObjectId and value "$foreignKey"

Joe, thanks so much for your response.  I can't tell if it's the correct answer because my correct answer was to pivot to using Spring Data's aggregation support rather than the driver aggregation support.
